# How to save the save the full file path in mysql table when using the upload form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i save the full File path in mysql table?

Presently the mysql storing the path name as follows

> F:Xammphtdocsdrnirajvoraappointment/uploads/0stock-illustration-4507047-set-of-colored-planets.jpg

But it should save like this

> F:Xammp/htdocs/drnirajvora/appointment/uploads/0stock-illustration-4507047-set-of-colored-planets.jpg

Here is my code to save the file

```
        public function uploadfiles()
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['fileupload']))
        {
            $errors= array();
                        $connection = db::factory('mysql');
                        $user_id=$_SESSION['userid'];   
            foreach($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
                {
                $file_name = $key.$_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$key];
                $file_size =$_FILES['fileupload']['size'][$key];
                $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $file_type=$_FILES['fileupload']['type'][$key]; 
                if($file_size > 2097152)
                        {
                        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
                        }   
                $upload_dir = ROOT;
                $desired_dir=ROOT."/uploads/";
                if(empty($errors)==true)
                    {
                    if(is_dir(ROOT."/uploads/")==false)
                        {
                        mkdir(ROOT."/uploads/", 0700);      // Create directory if it does not exist
                        }
                    if(is_dir(ROOT."/uploads/".$file_name)==false)
                        {
                        $file_path=ROOT."/uploads/".$file_name;
                        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_path);
                        $query="INSERT into uploads (`User_Id`,`File_Name`,`File_Path`,`File_Size`,`File_Type`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_path','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
                        mysql_query($query);
                        }
                        else
                        {                                   // rename the file if another one exist
                        $new_path=ROOT."/uploads/".$file_name.time();
                        rename($file_tmp,$new_path) ;
                        $file_path=$new_path;   
                        $query="INSERT into uploads (`User_Id`,`File_Name`,`File_Path`,`File_Size`,`File_Type`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_path','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
                        mysql_query($query);


                }
                else
                {
                print_r($errors);
                }
        }
        if(empty($error))
        {
        //echo "Success"; exit;
        return true;
        }
        return false;
}
    }
```

Comment: show where you are defining ROOT

Comment: define('ROOT',dirname(__FILE__)); here wher i defined the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_query is deprecated in the newest PHP and it's also not so safe. I'd highly suggest switching to Mysqli or PDO.

To answer your question though, try using mysql_real_escape_string() on your variables before inserting them in the DB. It will escape special chars.